# translate large queries to linq to Entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a few very large queries which I need to convert it linq because we are using Entity framework and I cant use stored procedures(breaks compatibility with other data bases).

using tool like linqer didnt even help and even if I get it to work with some mods to generated linq, there is a huge performance issue.

so, what is the best option in a situation like this where EF fails?

please don't ask me to divide it into small queries cause that's not possible.

Comment: Please give an example that demonstrates the size and complexity you're dealing with.

Comment: Are you able to use EntitySQL or you strictly want linq expressions?

Comment: @Bigsby sorry but cant share the code, its a sql with more than 300 line of code with a lot of join and aggregation in it

Comment: @vittore, we are using EntitySql I think now, but even when I write it with linq experssions still performance is the problem where I have to return a lot of data.

Comment: What do you mean by EF fails exactly? Does that mean you will not use EF going foward?

Comment: @pabbasian I don't care about your actual code. I'm just asking for a model that we can work from in an abstract sense. Generally speaking, "lots of joins" means you should be moving some stuff to views. But, for that to be an actual answer, the context needs to be known.

Comment: @Bigsby we want to be database independent.

Comment: Well are you sure it is ef performance issue , and not just query being way to bad to execute? Can you give us example of what you are doing ? 
Most likely you are trying to get multiple levels of heirarchy in one shot, that forces EF to do hundreds of request to db , while you really need to create your own mapper and use SP with MARS.( Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx)

Comment: @vittore there are analysis queries, the problem would be solved if I could use SP or a view, but since its breaks compatibility with other databases for our code first approach, I cant use them.

Comment: You still can use EF views and functions. But still show the queries.

Comment: @vittore, how and is it going to to work on mysql?

Comment: check this article http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/02/08/10175.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving this to an "answer" because what I want to say is too long for a comment.

It sounds like you're running into an inherent limitation to ORMs. You won't get perfect performance trying to do everything in code. It sounds like you're trying to use an ORM like a T-SQL interface rather than a mapping between objects and a relational instance of data.

You say you want to maintain compatibility between databases but that's already a nonstarter if you consider schema differences from database to database. If you're already implementing a schema validation step so you ensure your code doesn't break, then there should be no reason why you can't use something like views.

You can say you don't want to support these things all day long but the simple point is that these things exist because they address certain problems. If you wholesale abandon them, then you can't really expect to get rid of the problem. Some things the database simply does better.

So, I think you're expecting something out of the technology that it wasn't meant to solve. You'll need to either reevaluate your strategy or use another tool to accomplish it. I think you may even need a couple different tools.

What you've been doing may have worked when your scale was smaller. I could see such a thing working for quite a while actually. However, it does have a scale limit, and I think you're coming up against it.

I think you need to make a determination on what databases you want to support. Saying "we support all databases" is untenable. Then, compare features and use the ones in common. If it's a MS SQL vs. MySQL thing, then there's no reason why you can't use views or stored procedures.

Comment: totally agreed with you but its not my decision, thanks for time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out LinqKit - this is a very useful tool for building up complex large EF queries.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx